# How to create Subdomains in Development environment with VIteJS?

Tags: subdomain, vite

I have the following subdomains:

- admin.myapp.dev
- buyers.myapp.dev
- sellers.myapp.dev

I tried running several servers on different ports but those didn't work.

What is the correct way to config the ViteJS to resolve those subdomains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve theses subdomains, use [vite's `server.proxy` option](https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-proxy).

```
server: {
    proxy: {
      // forward localhost:3000/admin -> to -> admin.myapp.dev
      '/admin': {
        target: 'admin.myapp.dev/'
      },

      '/buyers': {
        target: 'buyers.myapp.dev'
      },
      
      '/sellers': {
        target: 'sellers.myapp.dev'
      }      
    }
  }
```

You can also change the origin or rewrite the endpoint, even with RegEx. Please check the [offical doc](https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-proxy) about this point.